# doing a query match based on current item in sitecore

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore6

i want to add a droplink source that queries for aliases of the current item, basically the query should look like this:

```
/System/Aliases//*[@Linked item=??]
```

the value i want to match the `Linked item` field is the current item path of the droplink. How can i achieve this?

i'm using sitecore 6.5

**EDIT**

would this work?

```
/System/Aliases//*[@Linked item=$path]
```

Comment: Is this for a template droplink source? Because if you're talking about editing an item say in the content editor, there's already an alias menu option that shows any aliases that point at that item.

Comment: @divamatrix i know but what i now want is a droplink in order to be able to select one among the many alias an item may have, this is for SEO purposes

Comment: So you're saying that you just want to be able to add a droplink with the options to be all the aliases that an item has?  (sorry if that sounds silly to ask.. just want to make sure I understand what you mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, no.  There isn't any out of the box way to dynamically set a data source like that because you don't have any way of passing the context item with a simple query.  However, you can create your own custom field type to handle that which gives you the full api and in fact the alias box when you click the aliases button has all the code you need. Adding new field types is kind of tricky though.  If you want to go through the steps of adding your own custom field, I'd start here:  http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx.  It's using the custom checklist as a base.. but I think more than anything you can use that as a model for building your own.